# Unexpected NameError in Python without syntax error

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm trying to write in Visual Studio Code for Linux a simple roll dice program, but for some reason I have an unexpected NameError that makes me mad.

This is my code:

```
from random import randint

class Dice:

    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        play = randint (1, Dice.sides)
        print (play)

dado = Dice(6)
roll()
```

When I try to run program it fails with this error:

**NameError: name 'roll' is not defined**

I don't understand why, I know is probably a very stupid thing, but I don't see any problem whit the name "roll"...

Comment: You need to create an instance of `Dice`. Try `Dice().roll()`.

Comment: Is this your code? Then how did you manage to define a class with methods without knowing how to use a class?

Comment: `roll()` is a method of the `dado` object.  So you need to call it as `dado.roll()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are doing Object Oriented Programming (OOP), which in Python, consists of classes.

The `roll` function is inside the `Dice` class, so just doing `roll()` is not enough.

You need to first create an instance of the class, and use that instance to run the `roll` function:

```
dice = Dice(6)
dice.roll()
```

As for your example, you could do this:

```
dado.roll()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of the class first. Also, there is an error in roll function - you should use self.sides instead of Dice.sides. So, resulting code should look like this:

```
from random import randint


class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sides = 6

    def roll(self):
        play = randint(1, self.sides)
        print(play)


my_dice = Dice()
my_dice.roll()
```

Comment: Thanks.

I misinterpreted the method in the class context trying to call a method without create an instance.